# Showing Results of MySQL SHOW tables On Website

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to display a list of tables in a database on my website, and I can't find a way that works to display the output of `SHOW tables` on the actual page. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";

//Create Connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Check Connection

if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SHOW tables";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        echo $row[];
        }

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be ,

```
while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo($table[0] . "<BR>");  
}
```